# Not able to find control in minimised window using UIAUTOMATION in c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation

Trying find a checkbox and few buttons from a windows application. When application window is active, able to toggle and invoke button patterns but when window is minimised, getting null reference, find the sample code below

```
PropertyCondition nameProp = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "chkLan");
chkLanCntrl = loginWindow.FindFirst(Treescope.Children, nameProp);
TogglePattern toggleP = (TogglePattern) chkLanCntrl.GetCurrentPattern(TogglePattern.Pattern);
toggleP.Toggle();

FYI 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wppUY.jpg
```

Comment: Can you share some more infomation? A screenshot of the application for example?

Comment: Updated the image